# Need to change permissions for a file/folder

Tags: permissions, textpattern

In the diagnostics sections in textpattern, it's giving me the error:

"File directory path is not writable:...html/textpattern/files" (took out beginning of path)

I changed the permissions for the textpattern folder, and the folder named "files", which is in the root folder not in the textpattern folder, but it's still giving the error. Do I need to change permissions for all enclosed items of the textattern folder and not just the folder itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I got you wrong but I suppose you simply have to change the path to the files folder in your admin panel from "…html/textpattern/files" to "…/html/files".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on a *nix system...

It sounds like you want to change the permissions recursively.

A quick fix might be to change the permissions like so:

```
chmod -R 777 html/textpattern
```

This command will go through every folder and file and change its permissions (the `-R` turns on the recursive bit).

Warning, this is very broad and not a good idea for production.

A better approach would be to change the permissions at a finer level of granularity.  Google for "Linux file permissions" or type `man chown` at the shell.

Comment: Where would I put this bit of code? What I did before was change the permission directly in the ftp program.

Comment: And the site's hosted on GoDaddy.

Comment: You need to do it via the SSH console, GoDaddy probably won't let you do it, I think some FTP let you do it but I don't remember (been a long time since I used FTP).  Good luck!